# ec2 publickey error after sucessfully connecting for 1-2 weeks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have gotten a publickey error after a week or 2 of successfully connecting my ec2 instance on AWS educate. Normally I would put in:

```sh
ssh -i /Users/sophiadhanani/pemname.pem \
  ubuntu@ec2-18-xxx-236-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and it would connect.

Now when i do this and put `-vvv` I get the following in the last couple of lines of code.

```
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/sophiadhanani/mist5900new.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:vzqKmzkmKgjN8Z5FIflSHnSzcfxBhzzec7ov0ODCCJI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

I am not changing anything at all and I am being forced to recreate a new instance completely.

I have a new instance now that is working but what can I do to ensure that I won't get the publickey error again eventually?

Comment: I would reach out to Amazon - it sounds like the instance goes away with either time or because of non-use.

Comment: Can you connect using browser-based ssh client? It could help you login and inspect the instance easily.

Comment: Please check the IP address of your Amazon EC2 instance. If it was stopped and started, it might receive a different IP address (which is part of the DNS Name being used).